# Comparing objects of value type N

Tags: .net, compare, value-type

What is the best way to compare objects of value type N?  So I want to do a String, Integer, DateTime, etc comparison depending on the type of the object.

Comment: Just a small note, String is not a value type. It's a reference type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine(Compare<int>(1, 3));
    Console.WriteLine(Compare<string>("wil", "test"));
    Console.WriteLine(Compare<DateTime>(DateTime.Now, 
        DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static int Compare<T>(T a, T b) where T : System.IComparable
{
    System.IComparable comparer = a;
    return comparer.CompareTo(b);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
IEqualityComparer<T>
```

Where T is the type you want to compare.

[IEqualityComparer(T) Interface (System.Collections.Generic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx)

...you could also fall back on `Object.Equals()` and `ValueType.Equals()`

Answer (score 1):

Every simple types implements `IComparable` interface